# How to choose cssSelector value in Chrome browser using chrome Developer Tool(F12)?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

How to choose cssSelector() from Chrome browser using Chrome Developer Tools?

Can you show an example for the below code?

```
WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("selector"));
searchBox.click();
```

How to chose the value for the SELECTOR field from the Chrome Developer Tool?-F12 in Chrome. Please explain with an example

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to Selenium like your tags imply, I guess you're trying to use

```
driver.findElements(By.className(".."));
```

or something similar, you need to be familiar with [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

for example if we inspect the stackoverflow logo we will see:

```
<div id="hlogo">
      <a href="/">
            Stack Overflow
      </a> 
</div>
```

So in this case we will use:

```
driver.findElements(By.id("hlogo"));
```

Or we can use a cssSelector by doing:

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#hlogo"));
```

Comment: can you show an example with findElement()? Also, please tell how can we chose a value without Div ID in it?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you question properly, thats what you need:

```
$$("your_selector")
```

For example:

```
$$("#id_of_element")
$$("[type="text"]")
```

Comment: How to chose the value for the SELECTOR field from the Chrome Developer Tool?-F12 in Chrome. Please explain with an example for my above qn

Comment: Right click on your element in UI, choose "Inspect element". This element will be revealed in the DOM. Now, check what attributes does the element has. Pick the ID (it's should be unique). If its doesn't have ID, try to use the class, if it's not unique, you should make more sophisticated selector. Read more about selector here: http://www.digitalfamily.com/tutorials/css-selectors/